# command: calabash-android setup. How to send static parameters “path”, “password”, “alias”?

Tags: android, bash, shell, testing, automated-tests

`calabash-android setup`, when i use this command in linux console, i want to send  static parameters `"path"`, `"password"`, `"alias"` It need for my bash script, my script generates `keystore` file and use settings in command `calabash-android setup`

How to send static parameters `"path"`, `"password"`, `"alias"`?

`calabash-android setup my.apk "path" "password" "alias"`

info calabash-android:

http://calaba.sh/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in another way, command `calabash-android setup my.apk` save in
`/.calabash_settings` 3 parameters and kind of like nothing else, I removed from his command script calabash-android setup and made rewriting `/.calabash_settings` adding dates and advance saved variables in the parameters of me.

`static_param="{\"keystore_location\":\"$path\",\"keystore_password\":\"$password\",\"keystore_alias\":\"$randomalias\"}"
echo $static_param > /.calabash_settings`

Now my test run! Thank you very much!